# add more than 2 values in cookies python

Tags: python

i'm trying to add more than 2 values in cookies python script.
Cookies values are supposed to be this way in the header

```
Cookie: AWSALB=Wpq++dLpIbyAkxZlCDLyZb5R4aJw0G5J9pYeW2jEQtCpDjpbt7aCTPi2Xo+gJd834M3t9BSv/GoEzgu3NiAtPmN3wXixRxiQnpduvfC5wb0wK14XO5crqMTss4Ou; PHPSESSID=ttsrnob9ir39bgqqf6qtjmtrq2;
```

it shows like this when i try to run the script

{'error': True, 'errorType': 'sessionExpired'}

This is my attempt

```
    headers = {"Connection":"close"}
    k = requests.get('site.com/api/test', headers=headers)
    session_id = k.cookies['AWSALB'], k.cookies['PHPSESSID']
    headers['Cookie'] = 'AWSALB={};','PHPSESSID={};'.format(session_id)
    print(session_id)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refresh you cookies periodically, probably by doing a login request first and then storing them from the response received.
After receiving new cookies, you can define them separately:

```
cookies = {
    "AWSALB": k.cookies['AWSALB'],
    "PHPSESSID": k.cookies['PHPSESSID'],
}
```

and send in your request:

```
k = requests.get(URL, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
```